# App crashes onBackPressed() with MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an Android app with Android Studio, however, my app crashes at runtime and I can't figure out why? My code looks fine and it has got no errors. I have an 'if statement' inside a public void onBackPressed().

```
//stop's the car sound that is currently being played when the devices back button is clicked
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mySound !=null) {
        mySound.stop();
        this.finish();

        if (mySound == null) {
            this.finish();
        }
    }
```

mySound is equal to a MediaPlayer.

My first 'if statement' is for when the back button is pressed (while the sound is playing), the sound will stop and the activity will close and go to the previous activity.

And my second 'if statement' is for when the back button is pressed (while the sound is NOT playing), the activity will close and go to the previous activity.

I have tried using || but that doesn't seem to work? Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

ANSWER:

```
if (mySound !=null) {
    mySound.stop();
    this.finish();
}

if (mySound == null) {
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: @JohnJoe So my Logcat right?

Comment: Now at what stage it crashes if !null means you can check null in else

Comment: @MSP yes yours . show  where you got your crash

Comment: @MSP Yes.......

Comment: @Charuka - My app runs perfectly until I click the back button. It crashes when there is NO sound being played, however, if the sound is being played and you click the back button it will work and go back to the previous activity. I've tried putting ==null in an else statement but it says 'else without if'?

Comment: you probably put that else inside your first if, `if(!null){
} else {
// null
}`

Comment: @JohnJoe Sorry, it doesn't crash. The app doesn't work when I click the back button if there is NO sound. However, if I play the sound and click the back button, it works and goes back.

Comment: My app does absolutely nothing when I click the back button if there is NO sound being played. @JohnJoe

Comment: @MSP wait! in your topic you said there is a crash what do you exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: Like what @Charuka suggested, you probably need a `if`  and `else`. Have you tried `if (mySound !=null) {
        mySound.stop();
        this.finish();}

        else {
            this.finish();
        }`

Comment: @JohnJoe - My app now works correctly. My 2nd if statement was inside my first if statement

Comment: @Charuka - Thank you! I had my 2nd if statement inside my 1st if statement! Silly but thank you

Comment: @MSP you are welcome :) good luck!